# Wcf ChannelFactory

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory

I have a question about WCF and Channel Factory usage.

On Host :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGetMessage 
{
    [OperationContract]
    string ShowMessage(Sample p, string Username, string Password);
}

[DataContract]
public class Sample
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public string ShowMessage(Sample p, string Username, string Password)
{
    return p.Name.ToString() + " - " + "Correct"; //Error line
}
```

On Client :

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IGetMessage
{
    [OperationContract()]
    string ShowMessage(Sample p, string Username, string Password);
}

[DataContract()]
public class Sample
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Sample p1 = new Sample();
    p1.Name = "ALEX";

    BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

    EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://MYURL/GetMessage.svc");

    using (var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IGetMessage>(myBinding, myEndpoint))
    {
        IGetMessage client = null;

        try
        {
            client = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

            MessageBox.Show(client.ShowMessage(p1, "abc","123"));

            ((ICommunicationObject)client).Close();
            myChannelFactory.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            (client as ICommunicationObject)?.Abort();
        }
    }

}
```

If I add on client as Service Reference, it works perfectly. I can get "ALEX - Correct" message.

When I test on WcfTestClient.exe, it works perfectly.

But, I have a problem when using on Winform with above codes. 
When I check on WcfServer Trace Log and Message Log;

> System.NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Line number:22

Line number 22: 
**p.Name.ToString()** on the Host's GetMessage.cvs.cs file.

I think, there is no problem on host. Problem is Client side.

I'd like to ask you how I made a mistake on the client side?

Regards.

Comment: Everything looks perfect. I can't see any diffs in the contracts...except you use () on client side attributes...but I think I'd eat my hat before thinking that was the problem.

Comment: I could not find the problem. According to the Wcf Trace Log and Message Log; the problem is Sample Class (passing object). I am sure that the problem is on client side. Because I do not have any problem on wcftestclient.exe or adding service reference.

Comment: Also, finally, I have added svc url as Service Reference and I changed end point address dynamically on Button_Click. It's working perfectly. If I can not find the solution, I will follow this way.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably good enough...but if you still wanna try something...wcf contracts have namespaces, and you can control that namespace with the [ContractNamespace] attribute. I put mine in the AssembyInfo.cs and prefix it for global scope: [assembly:ContractNamespace...] Just for yucks, try declaring it in client and server the same way...they might vary in a way that prevents deserialization on server.

Comment: You can look into the service reference (it's really just a folder with some gen'd code) and see that it largely does the same thing as your winforms client...maybe look for some differences there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, to solve the problem you only to do is adding the namespace property to ServiceContract and DataContract. be sure that the namespace is identical between the client and the server. the reason why we should do is an error occurred during serialization and deserialization, we must ensure that the service contract and data contract has a consistent namespace between the server and client.
Here is my example(Add this feature on both the server and client.)

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace ="http://mydomain")]
    public interface IGetMessage
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string ShowMessage(Sample p, string Username, string Password);
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://mydomain")]
    public class Sample
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Result.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks so much @Abraham Qian. Thanks for your correct solutions. The problem was namespace. Regards.

Comment: And thanks so much @Clay. Your solution was checking the namespaces too. The problem has resolved. Thanks again